# Кастомная кнопка с нестандартной зоной нажатия

Tags: android, android-button, android-customview

Как сделать такую кнопку?
[image: button]

Нажатие необходимо фиксировать в зоне до кривой линии.

Нашел в стандартных View - `ImageButton`, но там зона нажатия прямоугольная, что не подходит для моей задачи.

Comment: Вам тут вроде не нужна нестандартная зона тача, элемент не перкрывается другим и конфликта нет - ваша задумка будет только нервировать пользователя, которому с какой то стати нужно будет попадать только в половину контрола, вместо целого. Если вам нужно выделение при нажатии нестандартной формы, то сделайте кастомный селектор и на тач повесьте какой угодно причудливой формы бэкграунд. Внешне будет выглядеть, как нажатие на половинку, но зона тача будет полная. Если такое решение подходит, но вы не знаете как, пишите. Если непременно нужна именно нестандартная тач-зона, тоже пишите, разберемся.

Comment: @pavlofff Эта одна из кнопок панели внизу экрана http://i.stack.imgur.com/cnbkd.png
и тут получается, что если у них будут стандартные зоны, то кнопки друг друга перекроют. Подумал можно забить их зону фигурами (в частности кнопку check треугольником), и уже работать с ними, но я еще не сильно в этом разбираюсь и еще не понял как это реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

Можно переопределить `onTouchListener` и придумать способ определять, попал клик в область или нет. То, что нарисовано, похоже на дугу, поэтому я бы написал так:

```
public class MyCutomView extends TextView {
    // constructors will be here

    float radiusSquare;
    OnClickListener myListener;

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        radiusSquare = (float) Math.pow(Math.max(w, h), 2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float viewX = event.getX();
        float viewY = event.getY();

        // если событие в точке, которая дальше чем на radius
        // верхнего левого угла, то обрабатываем его
        if (radiusSquare < viewX * viewX + viewY * viewY) { // теорема Пифагора :)
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                Log.d("happy", "clicked");
                if (myListener != null) {
                    myListener.onClick(this);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        // события вне кликабельной области отправляются дальше
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * myListener будет возвращать клики из кликабельной области нашей вьюхи
     * (см. выше в onTouchEvent())
     */
    public void setSpecialOnClickListener(OnClickListener myListener) {
        this.myListener = myListener;
    }
}
```

Подписываемся на клики через `setSpecialOnClickListener()`:

```
    hello = (MyCutomView)findViewById(R.id.hello);
    hello.setSpecialOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast
                .makeText(MainActivity.this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: а зачем левый колбэк? `onTouchEvent()` шлет событие клика в стандартный `OnClickListener()`. Нужно просто `true` и `false` возвращаемые методом поменять местами (чтобы при регистрации клика в области, передавался на обработку стандартному колбэку - возвращал `false`, а при непопадании в область клик просто игнорировался - возврат из метода `true` сообщает, что событие обработано и дальнейшие действия не требуются), а собственный колбэк удалить вовсе.

Comment: я думал об этом, и мне эта идея не понравилась: код хуже читается. кроме того, никто не сказал, что клики вне области надо игнорировать: область слева может быть прозрачной, и там может быть другая часть интерфейса со своей жизнью.

Comment: Ну тогда хотя бы написать, как через этот колбэк подписаться на клики по области. Не каждый, кто будет читать ответ сможет понять, для чего он там. Так же не хатает кода интерфейса самого колбэка

Comment: Спасибо, дополнил.